# Oracle --> NOT A GROUP BY EXPRESSION ERROR

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is my query. I am not sure what cause the Not A group by expression error. Any help is much appreciated. =)

```
SELECT 
    DTA_PRODUCAO AS AF002_DTA_PRODUCAO
,   COD_MATERIAL AS AD001_COD_MATERIAL 
,   COD_FILIAL AS AD004_COD_FILIAL
,   NVL(SUM(DQTD_CONSUMOT),0)  AS AF002_DQTD_CONSUMOT
,  (SELECT NVL(SUM(DQTD_CONSUMOT),0) FROM MYDB.DSO_TERMICO M WHERE M.COD_FILIAL = D.COD_FILIAL AND M.CODPRO = D.COD_MATERIAL   AND M.ZTL_DATA >= SUBSTR(D.DTA_PRODUCAO,0,6)||'01' AND M.ZTL_DATA <= D.DTA_PRODUCAO) AS AF002_MQTD_CONSUMOT
,  (SELECT NVL(SUM(DQTD_CONSUMOT),0) FROM MYDB.DSO_TERMICO M WHERE M.COD_FILIAL = D.COD_FILIAL AND M.CODPRO = D.COD_MATERIAL   AND M.ZTL_DATA >= SUBSTR(D.DTA_PRODUCAO,0,4)||'0101' AND M.ZTL_DATA <= D.DTA_PRODUCAO) AS AF002_AQTD_CONSUMOT
FROM
    (SELECT 
       DTA_PRODUCAO
       ,CODPRO AS COD_MATERIAL 
       ,COD_FILIAL AS COD_FILIAL 
      , CASE WHEN DAUX.ZTL_DATA = TMP.DTA_PRODUCAO THEN DAUX.DIACONSUMO ELSE 0 END AS DQTD_CONSUMOT
      FROM MYDB.DSO_TERMICO DAUX
      INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT MYDB.DSO_TERMICO.ZTL_DATA AS DTA_PRODUCAO FROM MYDB.DSO_TERMICO) TMP ON SUBSTR(TMP.DTA_PRODUCAO,1,4)=SUBSTR(DAUX.ZTL_DATA,1,4))
  D
  GROUP BY 
  DTA_PRODUCAO,
  COD_MATERIAL,
  COD_FILIAL
  ORDER BY 2,1;
```

Comment: Does the subquery run successfully on it's own?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `SUM(M.DIACONSUMO)` in the subquery, rather than `SUM(DQTD_CONSUMOT)`?

Comment: 1-test your `From`. 2-Try to eliminate items from your `select` and `group by`  - you will find what causes the error

Comment: @DanBracuk, the subquery run successfully.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, I'm sure that I want SUM(DQTD_CONSUMOT).

Comment: @T.S when I eliminate the two last items from select the query runs ok, but I can't understand why. because I'm using an agregate function.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking. I don't think it is possible with `Group By`. Move those to `FROM` with join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand what is going on.  Here is your subquery:

```
 (SELECT NVL(SUM(DQTD_CONSUMOT),0)
  FROM MYDB.DSO_TERMICO M
  WHERE M.COD_FILIAL = D.COD_FILIAL AND
        M.CODPRO = D.COD_MATERIAL   AND
        M.ZTL_DATA >= SUBSTR(D.DTA_PRODUCAO,0,6)||'01' AND 
        M.ZTL_DATA <= D.DTA_PRODUCAO
) AS AF002_MQTD_CONSUMOT
```

Everything looks kosher.  The three fields mentioned in the `where` are in the `group by` clause.  The expression `DQTD_CONSUMOT` (which is importantly `D.DQTD_CONSUMOT`) is not, but it is in a `sum()`.  What could be the problem?

The problem is that this is a scalar subquery.  So the compiler interprets the `sum()` only within the subquery.  It says "This subquery wants to do a sum on `D.DQTD_CONSUMOT`, but that is not a `group by` expression.  Error!".

You could fix this by factoring out the "constant":

```
 (SELECT count(*)
  FROM MYDB.DSO_TERMICO M
  WHERE M.COD_FILIAL = D.COD_FILIAL AND
        M.CODPRO = D.COD_MATERIAL   AND
        M.ZTL_DATA >= SUBSTR(D.DTA_PRODUCAO,0,6)||'01' AND 
        M.ZTL_DATA <= D.DTA_PRODUCAO
 ) *  NVL(SUM(DQTD_CONSUMOT),0) AS AF002_MQTD_CONSUMOT
```

I suspect that you could also fix this by using analytic functions as well.  Something like:

```
sum(DQTD_CONSUMOT) over (partition by D.COD_FILIAL, D.COD_MATERIAL, SUBSTR(D.DTA_PRODUCAO,0,6))
```

or something like that.  Without sample data and results, it is very hard to figure out exactly what all this is doing.

Comment: Or he can move those subqueries to From and join them as tables - viola